# koalas for PySpark: why does it try to run Python on Driver machine?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-koalas

I'm trying to use `koalas` library for PySpark 2.4.5

I have set up `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` and `PYSPARK_PYTHON` environment variables and created a Spark session with client deployment mode:

`spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().master("yarn").getOrCreate()`

With this Spark session I have created a couple of PySpark dataframes and created `koalas` dataframes from them (via `.to_koalas()` method).

But when I have tried to use `.loc[]` and `.filter(...)` operation on my koalas dataframes I got the following error:
`java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/local/bin/python3.7": error=2, No such file or directory`

The path `"/usr/local/bin/python3.7"` was exactly the path to Python interpreter on my Spark Executor hosts (and it was set in `PYSPARK_PYTHON` environment variable).

After two hours of crying I've tried to add a symlink to Python interpreter on my driver machine at the same path: `/usr/local/bin/python3.7`, and it helped: my script stopped failing with this error.

But on production environment I won't have such an option to set such symlinks so easily. And I still have a question: why does koalas searches for Python interpreter on driver by `PYSPARK_PYTHON` instead of `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON`?